# How to change visibility of item using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, visibility

My application requires that users upload a set of required documents (Upload #1, Upload #2, Upload #3).  When an upload completes, it returns the requirement identifier (req_id).

The page displays a list of the requirements, and currently changes the class from "missing" to "complete" once a particular item is uploaded.  However, I'd also like to change the visibility of a "delete" icon from hidden to visible once the upload is complete as well.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="missing" rel="1">
        <span class="link">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Upload #1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="controls">
            <img src="download.png" class="download" <? if ($req_item['class'] == "missing") { echo 'style="visibility: hidden;"'; } ?> >        
            <img src="trash.png" class="delete" <? if ($req_item['class'] == "missing") { echo 'style="visibility: hidden;"'; } ?> > 
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="missing" rel="2">
        <span class="link">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Upload #2</a>
        </span>
        <span class="controls">
            <img src="download.png" class="download" <? if ($req_item['class'] == "missing") { echo 'style="visibility: hidden;"'; } ?> >        
            <img src="trash.png" class="delete" <? if ($req_item['class'] == "missing") { echo 'style="visibility: hidden;"'; } ?> > 
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="missing" rel="3">
        <span class="link">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Upload #3</a>
        </span>
        <span class="controls">
            <img src="download.png" class="download" <? if ($req_item['class'] == "missing") { echo 'style="visibility: hidden;"'; } ?> >        
            <img src="trash.png" class="delete" <? if ($req_item['class'] == "missing") { echo 'style="visibility: hidden;"'; } ?> > 
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
function stopUpload(success, req_id){

    if (success == 1){
        $('#upload_result').html('<span class="msg">Success!<\/span>');
        $("ul li[rel=" + req_id + "]").removeClass().addClass('complete')
        $("ul li[rel=" + req_id + "]").child('.controls').child('.delete').css('visibility','visible')
    }
    else {
        $('#upload_result', window.parent.document).html(
        '<span class="emsg">Error!<\/span>');
    }
    $('#upload_progress').hide();
    return true;

}
```

Comment: I haven't found a question in your post yet...

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `child` method. Use `children()` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use jQuery, replace

```
$("ul li[rel=" + req_id + "]").removeClass().addClass('complete')
$("ul li[rel=" + req_id + "]").child('.controls').child('.delete').css('visibility','visible')
```

By:

```
$("ul li[rel=" + req_id + "]").removeClass().addClass('complete').find('.controls .delete').show();
```

However, you should use CSS for this. So keep your original jQuery and add this to CSS:

```
ul li .controls .delete {
    display: block;
}
ul li.complete .controls .delete {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change

```
$("ul li[rel=" + req_id + "]").child('.controls').child('.delete').css('visibility','visible')
```

to

```
$("ul li[rel=" + req_id + "] .controls .delete").show()
```

Should work nicely.

Rather than visibility, I'd tend to use the display property - `display:none;` or `display:block;` or `display:inline;`

Comment: Your code is not equal to the original code. To select children, you have to use `>` (parent-child selector): `$("ul li[rel=" + req_id + "] > .controls > .delete")`.

Comment: display removes the image completely and shifts everything around accordingly, I think what op was trying was just to make the image invisible

Comment: @RobW: Correct, however given the original HTML it's fine - there's no instance of the li having more than one .control descendent - in fact, `$("ul li[rel=" + req_id + "] .delete")` would work as well.

Comment: @annonymously: Yes, was wondering that. The lack of any real question made it hard! .show() and .hide() are nice and simple and tend to "Just Work"; obviously his line with the visibility wasn't working :S

Comment: @Rob, that's not true. The > is used to only select a direct child. In this case it adds no value at all.

Comment: @Richard `.children()` is equivalent to `>`.