# JS | How to change style=visibility:hidden to visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<p><b id="msg" name="msg" style="visibility:hidden; color:#3399ff;">msg</b></p>
```

JS:

```
$('#url').on('change keyup paste',function(){
$('#msg')style.visibility('visible');});
```

How can i do it please?

Comment: You forgot the dot before `style`

Comment: `$('#msg').css("visibility", 'visible');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change visibility of item using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548506/how-to-change-visibility-of-item-using-jquery)

Comment: $("#msg").toggle(); will help you

Answer (score 6):

You are mixing both Javascript and Jquery.

With Jquery, just change the css property using the function `css()`

```
$("#msg").css('visibility', 'visible');
```

or with pure Javascript

```
document.getElementById("msg").style.visibility = "visible";
```

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery, you can use the `.css` method like so :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#msg').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <b id="msg" name="msg" style="visibility:hidden; color:#3399ff;">message</b>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#msg').css('visibility','visible')
//or: initial => Sets this property to its default value
$('#msg').css('visibility','initial')
//or: inherit => Inherits this property from its parent element.
$('#msg').css('visibility','inherit')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><b id="msg" name="msg" style="visibility:hidden; color:#3399ff;">msg</b></p>
```